# Does the JVM only support a proper subset of IEEE 754's required features?

Tags: java, jvm, ieee-754

According to the following links:

http://sonic.net/~jddarcy/Borneo/

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf

Java only supports a proper subset of IEEE 754 standards. Does this mean this is the case for all JVM languages? (Is problem solvable at the bytecode level?) If I want to leverage hardware which support these features, is there a way to do this on Oracle's JVM? If not, does a fork exist that does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the case for all JVM languages. The global flags just aren't there.
No, there's no way to fix this.

More importantly, no, you shouldn't. While Prof Kahan may be an expert on numerical computing, he's not on software engineering. Nor is he able to predict the future. Global FP state is a [very bad idea](http://arith.polito.it/foils/5_5.pdf) in todays multi-core world. For compliance, you have to artificially fuse the FP state of each thread into a single global state, and then you cannot reliably deal with individual errors anymore so you just have to bail out. Just great.

Comment: Professor Kahan knows a great deal more about software engineering than the peanut gallery gives him credit for.  He has always been perfectly clear on the point that global state is only one of many possible ways to satisfy the requirements of IEEE-754.  That hasn't stopped others from misinterpreting his writing on the subject, sadly.  Discussion of flags is also only one small part of the linked documents; there are many other (better) points contained therein for someone who can be bothered to read them.

Comment: Well, I can argue the same about his "Imaginery" class. There is really no implementation difference implied between the `x + ı*y` and `(x,y)` notations. Implementation is bits; notation is textual, and any first-year student should be able to write a tranform between the two textual formats. He also gets the Ariane V disaster wrong. He pretends that it would have worked with IEEE754 logic; in reality that would just report the same overflow in a different manner. The rocket would have been blown up the same if the overflow exception would have been an overflow bit; that was 100% by design.

Comment: the crucial point of Kahan's suggestions for an Imaginary class is not the syntax used to represent it, but that you can get the correct result in certain cases where it's actually *impossible* to get the right answer if you only have Real and Complex types (at least, not without rolling your own Imaginary and Complex implementations).  I can find plenty of things to quibble with in that document, but you can't simply dismiss it out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leverage hardware specific features which the JVM does not use, you are likely to need to use C or assembly and call this via JNI.  Most of your code can still be in Java, but it doesn't have to solve everything.

Note: if you are doing this for performance reason you have to be careful that your "improvement" is not actually slower (sometimes much slower)